# How to stop VS Code from auto indenting the expression inside a bracket?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
inl f _ =
    ()
```

Suppose I put the caret inside `()`, press enter + `a`.

```
inl f _ =
    (
        a
    )
```

I get the above. I'd rather it did not auto indent and instead did the following.

```
inl f _ =
    (
    a
    )
```

I have the following in the `language-configuration.json` file.

```
{
  "comments": {
    "lineComment": "//",
  },
  "brackets": [["{", "}"], ["[", "]"], ["(", ")"]],
  "autoClosingPairs": [
    { "open": "{", "close": "}" },
    { "open": "[", "close": "]" },
    { "open": "(", "close": ")" },
    { "open": "'", "close": "'", "notIn": ["string", "comment"] },
    { "open": "\"", "close": "\"", "notIn": ["string"] },
  ],
  "autoCloseBefore": "}]) \n",
  "surroundingPairs": [
    ["{", "}"],
    ["[", "]"],
    ["(", ")"],
    ["'", "'"],
    ["\"", "\""],
  ],
  "indentationRules": {
    "increaseIndentPattern": "",
    "decreaseIndentPattern": ""
  }
}
```

[The guide](https://vscode-eastus.azurewebsites.net/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#indentation-rules) has a bit to say about the indentation rules.

> If there is no indentation rule set for the programming language, the editor will indent when the line ends with an open bracket and outdent when you type a closing bracket. The bracket here is defined by brackets.

I am guessing the behavior I am experiencing is related to this. If you look at the config file, I purposely pasted empty rules in an attempt to avoid this, but it did not work. What should I do here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can set `"editor.autoIndent": "none",`

This is from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

```
  // Controls whether the editor should automatically adjust the indentation when users type, paste, move or indent lines.
  //  - none: The editor will not insert indentation automatically.
  //  - keep: The editor will keep the current line's indentation.
  //  - brackets: The editor will keep the current line's indentation and honor language defined brackets.
  //  - advanced: The editor will keep the current line's indentation, honor language defined brackets and invoke special onEnterRules defined by languages.
  //  - full: The editor will keep the current line's indentation, honor language defined brackets, invoke special onEnterRules defined by languages, and honor indentationRules defined by languages.
  "editor.autoIndent": "full",
```